# How to properly animate an element vertically

Tags: css

I've got a bunch of elements coming into view on page load from the bottom of the page. So it looks like they're flying in from below and settling in their proper places. Right now what I'm doing is this, having a base class for all the elements like Row, in which I set transition all and position to relative. Then I have another set of classes Starting and Resting. In Starting I just set some position for top like 1000px so it's out of window bounds, then in Resting I set it to 0px and in javascript switch the classes one by one. This works however this seems very backwards, if the user has a 4k monitor or something it would show up, and also the scroll bar shrinks as this goes on since the elements are moving up a page. Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

PS. I understand that there is a work around for each issue I mentioned, like also maybe animating transparency so it's not visible at all on any monitor or setting positions to absolute and reserving the space on page so the scroll bar doesn't go crazy, however I'm not looking for hack like this (unless there is no other way). So what's the most straightforward and elegant design for this?

Comment: Don't use px use % or vh for your object start and end positions, this way you don't care if user monitor is 4k of 100k, and you don't need to change anything else.

Comment: @Abood so overall this is how it's done mainstreaM?

Comment: mostly, every CSS uses % values for responsible designs